# C# - Discord.Net - Trying to read audio from soundcloud and transmit it to discord

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, discord, discord.net

I am currently working on a discord bot that is able to play a song using soundcloud.
Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to get it to read from the url and stream it!
The bot it made in C#, and uses Discord.net library and ffmpeg for the audio.
Would love to hear some suggestions!

These are the three functions involved:

```
[Command("teste", RunMode = RunMode.Async)]
public async Task Play(IVoiceChannel channel = null)
{
    var audioClient = await JoinChannel(channel);
    var url = "https://soundcloud.com/campatechlive/campatech-live-feat- 
        matheus-moussa-arabian-system-vol-2-psy-trance-150-original-mix";

    var ffmpeg = new Ffmpeg(audioClient);
    await ffmpeg.SendAsync(url);
}

public async Task SendAsync(string path)
{
    using (var ffmpeg = CreateStream(path))
    using (var output = ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream)
    using (var discord = _client.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Mixed))
    {
        try { await output.CopyToAsync(discord); }
        finally { await discord.FlushAsync(); }
    }
}

private Process? CreateStream(string path)
{
    return Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "ffmpeg",
        Arguments = $"-hide_banner -loglevel panic -i \"{path}\" -ac 2 -f 
        s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    });
}
```

I'm guessing it's something on the ffmpeg arguments, but can't kind of figure out what.

I've tried a bunch of different arguments on ffmpeg, but none of them worked.
Anyone can lend me a hand?

Comment: please remove the screenshot of text ... add the actual text instead ... format as code

Comment: Can you post the ffmpeg logs? (printed on `stderr`). Nothing ffmpeg looks wrong. Have you tried to output to a file? If it plays, then your problem isn't ffmpeg..